# Why is the definition of adultery different for men and women?

Tags: women, marriage, adultery

> Narada Smriti 12.78 Intercourse is permitted with a wanton woman, who belongs to another than the Brahman caste, or a prostitute, or a female slave, or a female not restrained by her master (nishkâsinî), if these women belong to a lower caste than oneself; but with a woman of superior caste, intercourse is prohibited.

Why are men allowed to have sex outside the institution of marriage but women are not?

Nithin Sridhar, an Indic scholar, in his [blog](http://indiafacts.org/sa%E1%B9%85graha%E1%B9%87a-an-indic-view-on-adultery/) on the Hindu view of adultery writes:

> The definition of adultery was confined to:
>
> 1) Men—either married or unmarried– having sexual relationship with
>   married women
>
> 2) Married women having sexual relationship outside of marriage.

Is this not misogynistic?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109051/discussion-on-question-by-hindu-feminist-why-is-the-definition-of-adultery-diffe).

Comment: The Narada Smriti is primarily a book of law as per this link rather than anything religious: https://books.google.com/books?id=V552bAz5xFAC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=narada+smriti+12.78&source=bl&ots=G6stf2txuY&sig=ACfU3U3FmDw8QpBRnR8Kyi2iZk9JXBPQ5A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMsN3goPPpAhUP7awKHV1WA4gQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=narada%20smriti%2012.78&f=false
The wiki article also describes it as such. Hence this question would not have an answer in a religious hindu site.

Comment: Why is this closed as a duplicate of the other? The title question here is asking "Why is the definition of adultery different for men and women?" whereas the other question is about authenticity of a particular verse. Both are separate things.

Comment: @user1952500 Hindu "Law" Book means Hindu dharma shastra. It's a religious text. The verse quoted is from [a chapter](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe33/sbe3344.htm) titled "THE MUTUAL DUTIES OF HUSBAND AND WIFE".

Comment: Why did you delete your other question? ([Does Padma Purana ask Devadasis to indulge in prostitution?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40679/does-padma-purana-ask-devadasis-to-indulge-in-prostitution))